# Android Emulator for HTC / Motorola

Tags: android, emulation

What if we really need HTC emulator? Because sometimes each brand has different system management....

I can find addon for Samsung Galaxy Tab but nothing for other brands.

I am having a problem reproducing errors on HTC device while other devices runs well.

I created a battery widget which runs well on Samsung but some users using HTC and Motorola claim that battery level is not showing correct values.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create virtual devices to emulate HTC Evo 4G, Google/HTC Nexus One and T-Mobile/HTC G1

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/common-android-virtual-device-configurations/

Comment: But this is limited to "emulate" the look only. How to really emulate the device specific in details. Like how the battery management level in Motorola / HTC. They must be different in each brand.